# How to get height of UITableView placed in another UITableView in Cell as childViewController

Tags: ios, uitableview, childviewcontroller, uitableviewautomaticdimension

I'm struggling with wired kind of problem. I have `UITableView` with one cell. This cell is only holding containerView with `childViewController` (second `tableView`). My problem is that, first tableView(parent) must have `UITableViewAutomaticDimension` row height but it doesn't work (It dosen't know correct size of that cell with second `tableView`). 
How to get correct size of second `tableView`) ?

[image]

Second tableView (`inside Cell`) have scrollingEnabled turned off (`tableView.scrollEnabled = false`), first tableView must have correct size of second tableView in order to provide correct scrolling experience.

Comment: provide an image in order to be clearier

Answer (score 0):

Since a `UITableView` inherits from `UIScrollView` you can use the `contentSize` property to get this information. This is how the scrollbar works on the side.

I have done a similar thing before (long ago), so the following is somewhat hazy/ irrelevant/ unessecary. There might be some gotchas with unknown/unrendered cell heights in the embedded tableview. I rememeber having to set the tableview height to a large number (forcing all cells to render) fetching the `contentSize` then resetting the tableview height to the `contentSize.height`.

Answer (score 0):

Are you shure you really need second table view? If you have just one cell probably you don't need it. I recommend you to calculate table view height as the summ of it's cells heights. If cells of embedded table view have constant height it could be simple. In other case you also could calculate cells height.